# Can a convention be mandatory?

Tags: meaning

I am referring to the following meaning of the word *convention*

> [C1] a usual or accepted way of behaving ...

[[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/convention)]

I think that a *convention* cannot be mandatory but I would like to get some other opinions.

### EDIT

Perhaps some background will help provide more context.
I am a computer programmer. There are many computer programming languages. Each language has syntax. If a program is written that does not use correct syntax, it cannot run. So I would say that syntax is mandatory. Apart from syntax, there are conventions. The idea behind the conventions is to make it easier for computer programmers to read each other's code. Some programmers insist that these conventions are mandatory. I don't think they are. Hence my question.

Comment: Note that CED adds a forceful rider/caveat.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth CED = Cambridge English Dictionary?

Comment: I think the name switched from 'Cambridge English Dictionary' to 'Cambridge Dictionary'; 'CD' looks odd. // But quotes should be linked where possible, & always attributed.

Comment: If it's law, then it's mandatory. Behavior has no axiom; that's why we have to pass laws in the first place.

Comment: Since you’re a programmer, consider that some conventions like where the o place braces in C or how many spaces a tab should contain or a even that of converting tabs to spaces can be codified in a coding standard.  At that point it’s a convention but also mandatory for your project.

Comment: @Jim I am referring specifically to coding conventions as opposed to coding standards. An organization will define coding standards which are mandatory for all code written by that organization. I am asking only about conventions.

Comment: Who are these programmers that don't know the difference between "convention" and "law"?  Tell your boss and get them fired.

Comment: @RonJohn the motivation behind the question was just for my peace of mind. I don't want to invest in convincing them that there is a difference between convention and mandatory. I just wanted to see if my understanding of the meaning of the terms is correct.

Comment: Your comment about convention vs standards is right on point.  Things can be convention in some environments and standards(mandatory) in others.  If I write software for my own use I can violate convention all I want as long as the compiler accepts it and generates the machine code I expect.  If I get a job writing software the organization may enforce standards that are the same as the conventions I ignored and fire me if I do not comply.  The books written about the language will still call them conventions because the compiler does not enforce them, but my organization may enforce them.

Comment: @Abra - So your Question is: “If I define *convention* as something that is not mandatory, can it ever be mandatory??”

Comment: @Jim Yes, your rewording of my question is correct, as far as I am concerned.

Comment: It can also go the other way.  Many years ago the FORTRAN standard said loop variables had to be integers.  I was using a compiler that did not enforce that requirement and my code was running fine.  That compiler was old and deprecated so another problem got me to change to a newer one that did enforce the standard.  I moved from an environment where loop variables being integers was convention to one where it was mandatory.  It took me a while to understand why my program stopped working because of the machine code the new compiler generated-it also did not give an error for the float index.

Comment: "I just wanted to see if my understanding of the meaning of the terms is correct."  You're right, they're wrong.  Computer programmers who don't know the difference have a serious problem.

Comment: "The [bus factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_factor) is a measurement of the risk resulting from information and capabilities not being shared among team members, derived from the phrase 'in case they get hit by a bus.'" which is why *conventions are considered mandatory* by your fellow programmers. It doesn't have to be in the rule book (administration has no idea anyway) for it to be an unspoken requirement in the interest of everyone's job security, and  not just your own.

Comment: @Mazura just to clarify, I am **not** referring to fellow programmers in my employer's organization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say that it would be unacceptable to speak of a 'mandatory convention' in the sense of 'convention' I'm sure you're intending. But more suitable definitions are

> **convention** [noun] ...
>
> (5) a rule, method, or practice established by usage; custom:
>
> - *the convention of showing north at the top of a map.*

and the related non-count usage:

> (6) general agreement or consent; accepted usage, especially as a
> standard of procedure.

[[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/convention)]

I'd say that these definitions largely cut across a legally enforced practice. Though as @John Lawler's driving example shows, a convention may be encoded into law.

Comment: So a _convention_ can be regarded as a _rule_ and hence is mandatory. Did I understand your answer correctly?

Comment: I was tempted to omit that. 'The convention of showing north at the top of the map' is an excellent guide to usage of the term. [Almost] everybody does it [because it's the done thing / used by almost everybody / helpful, clearest to understand ...] but no one _has_ to do it that way. 'It's the rule / norm / standard'. Think of 'rule' here as in the phrase 'as a rule', usual.

Comment: @Abra - that's sort of backwards. Rules are mandatory and likely based on convention, which is in the eye of the beholder. If you're the Federal government, marijuana is illegal. If you're my state, it's decriminalized. That's conventional wisdom vs. modern conventional wisdom, respectively. - There's a convention to roll through stop signs, which is unlawful. Just because everybody does it doesn't make it legal.

Comment: @Abra "So a convention can be regarded as a rule" No. a convention, in the sense you are using it, is something that has been informally agreed. There is an expectation that the convention will be followed, and if it is not, people may complain - but it is not mandatory. For example, it is a [social] convention that a gentleman will open a door for a lady, but it is not mandatory.

Comment: I can see a legal case arising where OP's question is discussed for days, with cogent arguments, based on most probable readings of various dictionary definitions, pehaps even 'specifying definitions' (qv) apparently proving both opinions right. Basically, as often this hinges on _which specifying definition (of perhaps 'rule') one chooses_.

Answer (score 3):

A convention is a common solution to a common problem. The etymology is still a good guide to what it means - *con* + *vent* = 'with' + 'come', coming together to solve a problem.

An obvious example is driving on the right versus left sides of the road. Which one gets picked is arbitrary; either will serve. ***BUT***, and it's a big *but*, **everybody** has to follow the **same** convention, or there will be more problems instead of fewer.

When a situation is binary, often one choice has to be made and followed by everyone. The interesting fact is how that choice is made, and how people figure it out. When you get to Australia, you will see signs telling you that people drive on the left side in Australia. When you get to the USA, you won't find signs like that. Customs differ.

An interesting example occurred in Oberlin, Ohio during the 1950s, during the installation of a new dial telephone system. For about a year, some bug in the system caused it to work normally, except that all phone calls ended abruptly after about 5 minutes. People adapted, and since you can get a lot of talking done in 5 minutes, many calls were unaffected.

However, many telephone calls have to  last longer than that, so they had to be re-started. The problem was similar to driving on the wrong side of the road. If a conversation between A and B terminated in the middle, both parties would want it to continue; but if they both dialed, the call wouldn't go through. And if both of them assumed the other would do it, the call wouldn't go through either. If A dials and B doesn't, or if B dials and A doesn't, success! But how to proceed?

As it happened, in Oberlin, the telephone subscribers developed their own convention immediately and universally. It was the obvious convention, apparently, because everyone hit on it and understood it immediately; even though it was not logically obvious, it was socially obvious, and that turns out to be the important thing with conventions.

So, what did they decide in Oberlin? If person A called person B in the first place and the conversation was dropped, it was person A who called back. They placed the original call and were assumed to have the motivation. Person B was the passive receiver of the original call, and remained so.

Later on, frequent callers might adopt alternate re-calling for long chats; but the original convention came into place almost instantly, and lasted as long as the telephone bug.

Comment: This convention has reappeared with mobile phone calls frequently dropping. I’m not sure if anyone remembered or we reinvented it with the same logic.

Answer (score 2):

There are two distinct questions here that need to be disentangled:

(1) Does saying 'it is a convention to do X' logically imply 'X is mandatory'?

(2) Is it possible for a convention to be mandatory?

The answer to the first question is **no**. That it is a convention to do X does not **by itself** imply that it is mandatory. If some of the OP's colleagues think that it does, they are wrong.

The answer to the second question is, however, **yes**. A convention can be made mandatory by something outside the convention itself. For example, as has been pointed out in the comments, an employer can make it mandatory that its employees behave in accordance with a certain convention; that is then a mandatory convention within that workplace. The term *mandatory convention* is thus not self-contradictory.

Comment: It's not mathematically self-contradictory, but it is certainly unusual. A convention that has become mandatory would seem to be no longer a convention, but rather a law.